# Problem with my database on the server

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, connection-string

I uploaded my site to a server and i cant use my database on it.
I cant take or use any information on it.

Im using Access Database with C# on web developer asp.net . 
this is the code of the connection string:
 return string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}", DAL.path);
DAL.Path is the path of the database file on the server.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Why have you chosen such an inappropriate data store for web-based applications? Jet/ACE is really not designed for that environment, and is going to work only under very low load and with carefully written code.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess here, but if the server you are uploading to is a 64bit Windows platform, then the standard Jet library is not available. I believe there is an equivalent package, but this would need to be installed to make use of it.